# Given minimal characteristic polynomial how to derive linear recurrence?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I was able to find minimal characteristic polynomial of the sequence of numbers using Berlekamp-Massey algorithm. For example, for a sequence 
$$
1,2,3,5,11,25,53,109,227,481,1022,2162,4563,9637,20375,43086
$$
I've found MCP 
$$
x^8 - 4x^7 + x^6 + 8x^5 - 7x^4 + 7x^3 + 3x^2 + x - 13
$$
How can I derive linear recurrence for a given MCP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably figured it out by now, anyway you can look in here [LINEAR RECURSIVE SEQUENCES](http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC6/ps/linear.pdf)

for an explanation. The general rule is that with your minimal polynimial you also get your coefficients for your recurrence. Here it would be

$a_{n-8}=4a_{n-7} -a_{n-6} -8a_{n-5} +7a_{n-4}-7a_{n-3} -3a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}+13a_{n} $

with initial 8 conditions

a(1)=1, a(2)=2, a(3)=3, a(4)=5 etc.

Comment: Thanks for link! It is really what i've been looking for. But your recurrence is wrong. Right one is
$$
a_{n}=4a_{n-1} -a_{n-2} -8a_{n-3} +7a_{n-4}-7a_{n-5} -3a_{n-6}-a_{n-7}+13a_{n-8}
$$

Comment: oh, it was really late when I wrote this, but yeah I mixed up the indices. glad I could help